# How to subset list by ID for specfic output

Tags: r

If I say I have a list of people who used cafeteria.

```r
Fruits   ID   Date
apple    1    100510
apple    2    100710
banana   2    110710
banana   1    120910
kiwi     2    120710
apple    3    100210
kiwi     3    110810
```

I want to select people who have took both apple and banana and my new dataset to contain people who qualify for this inclusion criteria and give:

```
ID
1
2
```

(because only ID 1 and 2 had both apple and banana in the dataset)

what code should I use in R?

Comment: But ID3 has an apple and banana too

Comment: Doesn't ID 3 have both an apple and a banana?

Comment: oh lol. they do

Comment: I just changed it! Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you could do something like

```r
data.frame(ID = names(which(sapply(split(df$Fruits, df$ID), function(x) {
   "apple" %in% x & "banana" %in% x 
}))))

#>   ID
#> 1  1
#> 2  2
```

This will give you the name of the IDs that contain both "apple" and "banana"

If you want the subset of the data frame containing these rows you can do:

```r
df[df$ID %in% names(which(sapply(split(df$Fruits, df$ID), function(x) {
   "apple" %in% x & "banana" %in% x 
}))),]

#>   Fruits ID   Date
#> 1  apple  1 100510
#> 2  apple  2 100710
#> 3 banana  2 110710
#> 4 banana  1 120910
#> 5   kiwi  2 120710
```

Comment: If I say I had another column that I had the name of each participants (ID), and wanted to identify ID and their names as an output, how should I expand my code?

Comment: @YsabelleBoo see my update. You can filter out the data frame using that approach, so that only the rows of the data frame with the IDs that contain both apple and banana are present. In the example, the Date column is preserved. Obviously a name column would be too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr package to check if any of the entries is an apple AND any of the entries is a banana per ID:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Fruits = c("apple", "apple", "banana", "banana", "kiwi", "apple", "kiwi"),
                 ID = c(1,2,2,1,2,3,3),
                 Date = c(100510,100710,100710,120910, 120710,100210,110810))

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(any(Fruits == "apple") & any(Fruits == "banana")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(ID) %>% 
  distinct()
```

In this case, the result is

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
     ID
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
```